# Uvs on mesh change in image viewer, different from UV editor? meaning I cant paint as mesh don't align

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

My uvs from combined meshes are different from what the image viewer is displaying,
And although my normal baking worked, I cant paint on my meshes because they dont align to the object.

First image is from my combined objects, you can see all the uvs present.
Second image is the uv on the bag changing when I enter texture mode, uvs dissapear and uv map changed..
3rd image is the combined objects normals baked but the uv worked here?...

If I enter texture painting mode it swaps the uv? and I cant paint on the other objects since their uvs don't exsist?? But the normal's bake fine... very confusing!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you selected the good UV map in the Properties panel > Object Data > UV Maps? Could you please pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Thanks moonboots, I managed to get it to work by joining the three objects together, and was then able to see that somehow the UV editor had some other info that hadn't come though - possible some glitch as I had tried using a multi-object baking plugin.

well in anycase I repacked the uvs the separated the models again, and now they seem to work fine - so was some sort of glitch. Thanks for taking the time to help though :)